# How to use Kodein in KMM?

Tags: kotlin, kmm, kodein

I have this initializer of **Kodein** in **commonMain** module:

```
@ThreadLocal
object CommonInjector {
    val kodeinContainer = DI.lazy {
        importAll(mainModule)
    }

    val mainModule = DI.Module("main") {
        bind<IAccountManagerGateway>() with singleton { AccountManagerGateway() }
        bind<GetAccountUseCase>() with provider { GetAccountUseCase(instance()) }
        bind<GetDeviceNameUseCase>() with provider { GetDeviceNameUseCase() }
        bind<SignInUseCase>() with provider { SignInUseCase(instance()) }
    }
}
```

However `instance()` doesn't work in KMM because of it relies on `reified` keyword that's not supported by KMM.

How to replace `instance()` here?

**UPD:**
**Android Studio** prints the next error on `instance()` calls:

```
'inline fun <reified T : Any> DI.Builder.instance(instance: ???): InstanceBinding<???>' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary
```

Comment: `... reified keyword that's not supported by KMM.` it IS supported, it's a normal language keyword.

Comment: @YektaDev thank you! I thought so due to **Android Studio**'s errors. I've updated my question.